# Invalid operation dist-ugprade

Tags: debian, apt, php, php5-gd

i'm running Apache 2 on Debian at my VPS. Naturally i have problem with restricted GD-library of my php package and i need to fix it (i need `imagerotate()` function). Before installing `php-gd` pugin it's necessary to update php 5.2 to php 5.3

my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
#deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
#deb http://security.debian.org lenny/updates main contrib non-free
#deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian lenny main
#deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

The problem comes after `apt-get dist-ugprade` executing:

```
/$ apt-get update
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org stable Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org stable Release
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org stable/all Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org stable/all Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org stable/all Packages
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org stable/all Sources
Reading package lists...
/$ apt-get dist-ugprade
E: Invalid operation dist-ugprade
```

What can cause this problem? How much should i wait while `Reading package lists...`? Is there any simple guideline for further php-gd installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo: `dist-upgrade` (in *upgrade*)

Comment: oh, really.. sorry for a stupid question..)